# Data parsed from an XML file renders %22% for " and %27% for '...how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am parsing data from an XML file and the XML has the character ' encoded as %27% and the character " as %22%. Those characters render in my HTML, so I end up with data like this:

> Pike%27%s Peak

or

> this is my %22%Quote%22%

I attempted to perform a string.replace(), but to no avail. I am such a newbie when it comes to parsing XML with javascript. I'm sure my code is way off, but that's why I'm posting this quest...can anyone help me out? Here's the code for my attempted string.replace():

```
function xmlencode(string) {
return string.replace(/'%27'/g,'\'').replace(/'%22'/g,'\"');
```

}

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

That's some proprietary encoding, that's nothing that is usually used in an XML file. Because of that, there is no standard way of decoding it.

You have some extra apostrophes in your function that keeps it from working:

```
function decode(string) {
  return string.replace(/%27%/g,"'").replace(/%22%/g,'"');
}
```

You can parse the hex code between the percent signs to get a function that works for any such entity:

```
function decode(string) {
  return string.replace(/%[\da-f]{2}%/gi,function(m) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m.substr(1,2), 16));
  });
}
```

Example:

```
alert(decode("%49%%74%%20%%77%%6f%%72%%6b%%73%%21%"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Guffa, I am spending another sleepless night trying to figure this out. I tried your code and it deciphered the alert message, "It Works!"...brilliant, you are a genius. I, on the other hand, still can't figure out how to get your code to fix the data coming in from the xml document. Is there a way I can get your code snippet to scan the xml before it renders to the page?

Comment: @Carlos: The easiest is to decode the string before it's parsed as an XML document, otherwise you need to loop through the nodes in the document and decode each value.

Comment: Sounds like that's above my paygrade...definitely don't know much about looping through childNodes. I'm pulling the xml from a remote server, so I'm not sure if I am able to decode before it is parsed. Thanks a bunch for your feed back. I appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: @Carlos: Perhaps you should investigate the source of the XML, to find out why it's encoded in such a strange way.

Comment: Will do, Guffa. Thanks again. BTW, great last name...mine is similar, minus one "S".